# Validation in angular reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

On page load, validation implemented on form without `dirty` or `touched`. what is the way around, to get rid of red until its get `dirty` or `untouched`.

**app.html**

```
    <div class="container my-5">
  <div
    class="row"
    [formGroup]="profileFrm"
    #pfrm="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
  >
    <div class="col-6 p-3 card">
      <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="firstName"
            placeholder="Enter your First Name"
            formControlName="fname"
            [class.is-invalid]="f['fname']?.invalid && f['fname'].touched"
          />
          <div *ngIf="(fname?.dirty || fname?.touched)">asdfsdf</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"
          (click)="onSubmit()"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" (click)="onReset()">
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <pre>
      Output<br/>
      Submitted : {{pfrm.submitted}}
      <hr/>
      Status : {{pfrm.status}}
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.ts**

```
this._fb.group({
  fname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
});
```

[image]

Comment: make sure references are consistent, you have `profileFrm`, `f['fname']` and `fname`.. try `profileFrm.fname`. also, try calling `.markAsPristine()` on the form